# I have Helvetica installed but it doesn't show up in the Fonts folder

Tags: fonts, adobe-photoshop

I have both "Helvetica" and "Helvetica Neue" typefaces installed but only the last one shows up in the Fonts folder even thought when I open Photoshop or any software I can use both.

How can I fix that and why can't I see the normal "Helvetica" on the Fonts folder? Thanks.

[image: Fonts Folder]
[image: Photoshop]

Comment: It may be hidden.  Try enabling "Show hidden files" enabled in Explorer's folder/View options...

Comment: Tried already, didn't work.

Comment: If you open a command prompt and head to `C:\Windows\Fonts` and do a `DIR`, is there a Helvetica.ttf (or similar) file listed?

Comment: Yes. Here, http://i.imgur.com/sjJvZND.png

Comment: I don't know what happened, but I was looking the Fonts folder again and now I have "Helvetica" there too... http://i.imgur.com/yfiKvDv.png - "Problem solved", I think :D